# Trouble getting VSCode to open Powershell v5.1 as the default shell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get the Integrated Console in VS Code to use the up to date version of Powershell installed on my machine. I have reviewed and followed the instructions in the following link.
http://vscode-docs1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/integrated-terminal/

The problem I encounter is if I have the Integrated Console closed and I use the Show Integrated Console command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> >Powershell: Show Integrated Console) then it opens Powershell v1.6. If I then hit the New Termainal button (plus sign by the shell selector) the new instance properly uses Powershell v5.1. How do I make it so that I do not have to open a new shell to utilize the current version of PS?

I have tried selecting Powershell using the popup dialog "You can change the default terminal shell by selecting the customize button." as well as the adding the following to my User Settings file.

```
"powershell.powerShellExePath": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Edit:
I should also note that Powershell v1.6 is also the version which starts with the below line added to my User Settings file.

```
"powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": true
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though `Get-Host` returns different versioning then `$PSVersionTable`. Both terminal shells have a `$PSVersionTable` of 5.1.